# I cannot send an Email using the Java Mail API the email is sent but is not received or displayed in the emails sent

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

When I click the send button the email is sent and no error is displayed but the email is not received nor does it appear in the emails sent. Any help is welcome.

**My Code config Email Class:**

```
public class Email {

    public static void sendEmail(){
        final String username = "my_email@gmail.com";;
        final String password = "my_password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }});
        try {

            final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("my_email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("my_receive_email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Subject");
            message.setText("Message");

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try  {
                        Transport.send(message);
                        System.out.println("Done");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code of my send button:**

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "SEND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new Email();
                Email.sendEmail();   
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is class I use:

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";
    private String user;
    private String password;
    private Session session;

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());
    }

    public GMailSender(String user, String password, String host) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        if (host != null) mailhost = host;
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
    }

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients, String absolutePath, String fileName) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            //message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
           // message.setDataHandler(handler);
            MimeBodyPart mbp1 = new MimeBodyPart();
            mbp1.setText(body);
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(mbp1);


            if (absolutePath != null) {
                MimeBodyPart mbp2 = new MimeBodyPart();

                String file = absolutePath;
                String name = "podpis";
                if (fileName != null) name = fileName;
                name += ".jpg";
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
                mbp2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                mbp2.setFileName(name);
                multipart.addBodyPart(mbp2);

            }
            message.setContent(multipart);

            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("GMAIL SENDER", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] data;
        private String type;

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            if (type == null)
                return "application/octet-stream";
            else
                return type;
        }

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";
        }

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attaching a file to it so you don't need two `MimeBodyParts`

That's the call:

```
String email = "email_adress_TO";

            if (email != null && email.length() > 2 && email.contains("@")) {
                final GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("your_email/name", "password", "hostname");
                try {
                    sender.sendMail("Title",
                                    "message",
                                    "email_adress_FROM",
                                    email,
                                    null,
                                    null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
```

Of course it's inside `AsyncTask`.

Sorry, I've totally forgotten about `JSSEProvider`. There you go:

```
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController
                .doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
                    public Void run() {
                        put("SSLContext.TLS",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                        put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                        put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                        put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                                "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try that.

Comment: I remove Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider()); and now have this error: GMAIL SENDER: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. x4sm17489835ljb.66 - gsmtp

Comment: Check my edit, I've provided this class. My mistake.

Comment: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587, i try port 25 and 465 but is not work

Comment: Where did you copy this code from?  There's so much unnecessary stuff in there it's hard to tell where it might be going wrong.  Start by fixing all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then update you post with the new code, and if it still doesn't work, post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  And make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).  You should not need JSSEProvider or ByteArrayDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmailSender {
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender = new JavaMailSender();

    public void sendEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String text) {
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setTo(to);
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setFrom(from);
        mailMessage.setText(text);

        javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado irmão.